# Build error under Windows when using KSyntaxHighlighting

Tags: c++, qt, cmake, kde-plasma

- [GitHub Action](https://github.com/ChungZH/notepanda/runs/661977625?check_suite_focus=true)
- [Action's config file](https://github.com/ChungZH/notepanda/blob/syntax-highlight/.github/workflows/build.yml)
- [GitHub Repo](https://github.com/ChungZH/notepanda/tree/syntax-highlight/)
- [Project's `CMakeLists.txt`](https://github.com/ChungZH/notepanda/blob/syntax-highlight/CMakeLists.txt)
- [KSyntaxHIghlighting's `CMakeLists.txt`](https://github.com/ChungZH/notepanda/blob/syntax-highlight/src/3rdparty/syntax-highlighting/CMakeLists.txt)

> TIP: on branch `syntax-highlight` but not `master`

I use  KSyntaxHighlighting in my project. But I can't build my project on **Windows** now.

ERROR log:

```
CMake Error at src/lib/cmake_install.cmake:51 (file):
  file INSTALL cannot find
  "D:/a/notepanda/notepanda/src/3rdparty/syntax-highlighting/build/bin/Release/KF5SyntaxHighlighting.dll":
  File exists.
```

Below is the command I executed

```bsh
git clone git://anongit.kde.org/extra-cmake-modules
cd extra-cmake-modules
mkdir build
cd build
cmake ..
cmake --build .
cmake --install .
cd ../../
cd src/3rdparty/syntax-highlighting
mkdir build
cd build
cmake .. -DCMAKE_PREFIX_PATH=../../../../extra-cmake-modules/build
cmake --build .
cmake --install .
cd ../../../../
mkdir build
cd build
cmake .. -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release -A ${{ matrix.cmakearch }} -DCMAKE_PREFIX_PATH=C: -DCMAKE_PREFIX_PATH=../src/3rdparty/syntax-highlighting/build
cmake --build .
cmake --install .
```

Below is the project's `CMakeLists.txt`:

```
# CMakeLists.txt

add_subdirectory(src/3rdparty/syntax-highlighting)

find_package(Qt5 COMPONENTS Widgets Svg REQUIRED)
include(cmake/KF5SyntaxHighlightingConfig.cmake)
find_package(KF5SyntaxHighlighting REQUIRED)

target_link_libraries(notepanda Qt5::Widgets Qt5::Svg KF5SyntaxHighlighting)
```

KSyntaxHighlighting's CMakeLists.txt:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.5)

set(KF5_VERSION "5.70.0")
project(KSyntaxHighlighting VERSION ${KF5_VERSION})

find_package(ECM REQUIRED NO_MODULE)
set(CMAKE_MODULE_PATH ${ECM_MODULE_PATH})
if(POLICY CMP0063)
    cmake_policy(SET CMP0063 NEW)
endif()

include(KDEInstallDirs)
include(KDEFrameworkCompilerSettings NO_POLICY_SCOPE)
include(KDECMakeSettings)
#include(KDEClangFormat)

include(FeatureSummary)
include(GenerateExportHeader)
include(ECMSetupVersion)
include(ECMGenerateHeaders)
include(ECMGeneratePriFile)
include(CMakePackageConfigHelpers)
include(ECMPoQmTools)
include(ECMQtDeclareLoggingCategory)
include(ECMMarkNonGuiExecutable)
include(ECMAddQch)
include(ECMOptionalAddSubdirectory)


ecm_setup_version(PROJECT
    VARIABLE_PREFIX SyntaxHighlighting
    VERSION_HEADER "${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/ksyntaxhighlighting_version.h"
    PACKAGE_VERSION_FILE "${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/KF5SyntaxHighlightingConfigVersion.cmake"
)

#
# Dependencies
#
set(REQUIRED_QT_VERSION 5.12.0)
find_package(Qt5 ${REQUIRED_QT_VERSION} NO_MODULE REQUIRED COMPONENTS Core Network Test)
option(KSYNTAXHIGHLIGHTING_USE_GUI "Build components depending on Qt5Gui" ON)
if(KSYNTAXHIGHLIGHTING_USE_GUI)
    find_package(Qt5 ${REQUIRED_QT_VERSION} NO_MODULE REQUIRED COMPONENTS Gui)
endif()
find_package(Qt5 ${REQUIRED_QT_VERSION} NO_MODULE QUIET OPTIONAL_COMPONENTS PrintSupport Widgets XmlPatterns)
set_package_properties(Qt5 PROPERTIES URL "http://qt-project.org/")
set_package_properties(Qt5Widgets PROPERTIES PURPOSE "Example application.")
set_package_properties(Qt5PrintSupport PROPERTIES PURPOSE "Example application.")
set_package_properties(Qt5XmlPatterns PROPERTIES PURPOSE "Compile-time validation of syntax definition files.")

find_package(Perl REQUIRED)
set_package_properties(Perl PROPERTIES PURPOSE "Auto-generate PHP syntax definition files.")

#
# allow to install the "differently" licensed syntax xml files instead of putting them in a QRC and link them in
#
option(QRC_SYNTAX "Bundle the syntax definition files inside the library as resources" ON)
add_feature_info(SYNTAX_RESOURCE ${QRC_SYNTAX} "Bundle the syntax definition files inside the library as resources")

#
# allow to turn of lookup for syntax files and themes via QStandardPaths
#
option(NO_STANDARD_PATHS "Skip lookup of syntax and theme definitions in QStandardPaths locations" OFF)
add_feature_info(FEATURE_NO_STANDARD_PATHS ${NO_STANDARD_PATHS} "Skip lookup of syntax and theme definitions in QStandardPaths locations")

#
# API documentation
#
option(BUILD_QCH "Build API documentation in QCH format (for e.g. Qt Assistant, Qt Creator & KDevelop)" OFF)
add_feature_info(QCH ${BUILD_QCH} "API documentation in QCH format (for e.g. Qt Assistant, Qt Creator & KDevelop)")

#
# Translations
#
if (IS_DIRECTORY "${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/po")
    ecm_install_po_files_as_qm(po)
endif()

# tell the framework if it shall use the syntax files from the resource
if (QRC_SYNTAX)
    add_definitions(-DHAS_SYNTAX_RESOURCE)
endif()

# skip standard paths?
if (NO_STANDARD_PATHS)
    add_definitions(-DNO_STANDARD_PATHS)
endif()
add_definitions(-DQT_NO_FOREACH)
add_definitions(-DQT_DISABLE_DEPRECATED_BEFORE=0x050d00)

#
# Actually build the stuff
#
include_directories(${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR})
add_subdirectory(data)
add_subdirectory(src)

# ATTENTION!

#if(TARGET Qt5::Gui)
    #add_subdirectory(examples)
    #if (BUILD_TESTING)
        #add_subdirectory(autotests)
    #endif()
#endif()

#
# CMake package config file generation
#
set(CMAKECONFIG_INSTALL_DIR "${CMAKECONFIG_INSTALL_PREFIX}/KF5SyntaxHighlighting")

if (BUILD_QCH)
    ecm_install_qch_export(
        TARGETS KF5SyntaxHighlighting_QCH
        FILE KF5SyntaxHighlightingQchTargets.cmake
        DESTINATION "${CMAKECONFIG_INSTALL_DIR}"
        COMPONENT Devel
    )
    set(PACKAGE_INCLUDE_QCHTARGETS "include(\"\${CMAKE_CURRENT_LIST_DIR}/KF5SyntaxHighlightingQchTargets.cmake\")")
endif()

configure_package_config_file(
    "${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/KF5SyntaxHighlightingConfig.cmake.in"
    "${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/KF5SyntaxHighlightingConfig.cmake"
    INSTALL_DESTINATION "${CMAKECONFIG_INSTALL_DIR}"
)

install(FILES
        "${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/KF5SyntaxHighlightingConfig.cmake"
        "${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/KF5SyntaxHighlightingConfigVersion.cmake"
        DESTINATION "${CMAKECONFIG_INSTALL_DIR}"
        COMPONENT Devel)

if(TARGET KF5SyntaxHighlighting)
    install(EXPORT KF5SyntaxHighlightingTargets
        DESTINATION "${CMAKECONFIG_INSTALL_DIR}"
        FILE KF5SyntaxHighlightingTargets.cmake
        NAMESPACE KF5::)
endif()

install(FILES "${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/ksyntaxhighlighting_version.h"
        DESTINATION "${KDE_INSTALL_INCLUDEDIR_KF5}"
        COMPONENT Devel)

feature_summary(WHAT ALL INCLUDE_QUIET_PACKAGES FATAL_ON_MISSING_REQUIRED_PACKAGES)

# add clang-format target for all our real source files
# file(GLOB ALL_CLANG_FORMAT_TEST_FILES autotests/*.cpp autotests/*.h)
# file(GLOB_RECURSE ALL_CLANG_FORMAT_SOURCE_FILES examples/*.cpp examples/*.h src/*.cpp src/*.h)
# kde_clang_format(${ALL_CLANG_FORMAT_TEST_FILES} ${ALL_CLANG_FORMAT_SOURCE_FILES})
```

Comment: Please provide a [mre] within the question without external links